# Programmatically writing a batch file to echo to stderr

Tags: batch-file, stderr

As a part of some integration tests I am working on, I need to write a batch file that echoes out to stderr on a windows box.  Currently I am using the following command:

```
md %UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ && cd %UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ && ( echo @echo off  && echo 'echo This is error line 1 1>&2' && echo 'echo This is error line 2 1>&2' && echo @echo on ) >>test-stderrout.bat
```

This should create a temp directory under the `%UserProfile%\tests\` directory.  Then Navigate to this temp working directory.  Then create a batch file with the following code:

```
@echo off
echo This is error line 1 1>&2
echo This is error line 2 1>&2
@echo on
```

However, instead the file contains:

```
@echo off
@echo on
```

I see that the first echo gets piped out into stderr instead of reading that as text to then be in the batch file.  Is it possible to to escape this somehow to allow the output to contain the redirect statement?

Comment: some special chars have to be escaped. Try:  `echo echo This is some text 1^>^&2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line should do what you want:

```
md "%UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\" && cd /D "%UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\" && ((echo @echo off) & (echo echo This is error line 1 1^>^&2) & (echo echo This is error line 2 1^>^&2) & (echo @echo on)) >> test-stderrout.bat
```

#### Changes to your code:

- the directory paths are enclosed in `""` to avoid trouble with whitespaces;
- switch `/D` is added to `cd` to change also the drive if necessary (I don't know your current drive);
- the `>&` in your `echo` lines are escaped like `^>^&` to be echoed literally;
- each `echo` command is enclosed within `()` to avoid trailing spaces;
- `&&` (conditional command separator) are replaced by `&` (unconditional command separator) because `&&` does not make sense between the `echo` commands; I kept it at `md` and `cd` to avoid echoing in case the directory could not be created for some reason;

Comment: ... and single `&` are sufficient (and may be better) than `&&`

Comment: True, @Stephan, thanks, I'll change it, except for `md`/`cd`, where it might make sense, if the directory could not be created for some reason...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed respond, this contained each of the individual fixes to the problems i was encountering.

Comment: I want to use line continuations on your 1 liner but I can't quite get it to work with `(` and `&` operators and it would also change the code slightly so I will refrain from doing so.

Comment: @DaveCousineau, if you show your attempt I might be able to support you…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`md c:\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ & cd C:\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906 & echo @echo off >> test-stderrout.bat & echo echo This is error line 1 1^>^&2 >> test-stderrout.bat & echo echo This is error line 2 1^>^&2 >> test-stderrout.bat & echo @echo on >> test-stderrout.bat`

tested it locally it appears to be working.

the secret sauce is to escape the `>` and `&` characters with `^` in your echo.

Comment: I just realized Stephan already answered your question in form of a comment before me.  Sorry, didn't mean to steal your answer Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming windows shell works more or less like *nix shells.

```
md %UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ && cd %UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ && echo @echo off >>test-stderrout.bat && echo 'echo This is error line 1 1>&2' >>test-stderrout.bat  && echo 'echo This is error line 2 1>&2'>>test-stderrout.bat  && echo @echo on >>test-stderrout.bat
```

You're creating a subshell and doing stuff inside of it, rather than doing what you intended, echoing each command to the test-stderrout.bat file.

I'm not positive in terms of windows shell, but that looks to me like what's going on, so as soon as you dump the () and just echo out the strings to the file, it should all work. Probably more elegant ways to do it, but I assume this would work.

Or you can follow even better string practices and always place the echo into '..', which is what I always do in shell scripts to avoid errors.

```
md %UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ && cd %UserProfile%\tests\e3f949d1219d4cad9288bf88d0fcc906\ && echo '@echo off' >>test-stderrout.bat && echo 'echo This is error line 1 1>&2' >>test-stderrout.bat  && echo 'echo This is error line 2 1>&2'>>test-stderrout.bat  && echo '@echo on' >>test-stderrout.bat
```

Comment: Batch works different. a) `echo 'string'` would include the single quotes to the output (and cause a syntax error when you try to run the resulting file) b) `(echo one & echo two)>file.txt just writes `one` and `two` to `file.txt`. There is no simple `variable=(command)` to put a commands output to a variable in Batch.

Answer (score 0):

Sample batch echoStdErr.bat prints to stderr see Processing line 21

```
@echo off
if .%1 == . for %%v in (echo goto:eof) do %%v Ver 1.0 Usage: %0 dirOpt [outfile{con}]

setlocal
:: Arg1
set opt=/b

:: Arg2
set out=con
if not .%2 == . set out=%2
:: echo cmdline if not going to con
if not .%2 == . echo %cd%^> %* > %out%

call :dir *.sys
call :dir *.dll
call :dir *.exe
goto :eof

:dir SUBRTN pathnames
:: Provide minimal feedback if not writing to con
if not %out% == con echo Processing %1 ... >&2
for %%v in (%1) do call :dir1 %%v
exit /b 0

:dir1 SUBRTN path
set cmd=dir %opt% %1
%cmd% >> %out%
exit /b 0
```

echoStdErr.bat /b x.txt

```
c:\tc2\s\ADDF\x64\Release> echoStderr.bat /b x.txt
Processing *.sys ..
Processing *.dll ..
Processing *.exe ..
```

echoStdErr.bat /b con {OR}
echoStdErr.bat /b

```
c:\tc2\s\ADDF\x64\Release> echoStderr.bat /b
ADPU160M.sys
ADPU320.sys
dddriver.sys
DDUsbDriver.sys
addf_sm.dll
afaapi.dll
bc_vbdll.dll
BIOSIntf.dll
mv_api.dll
storarc.dll
storelib.dll
storelib8.dll
storelibir-2.dll
storelibir-3.dll
storelibir.dll
storelibit.dll
ValidateDLL.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
WinIPMIDLL.dll
WUDFUpdate_01009.dll
Battery.exe
Beep.exe
BootPath.exe
Cables.exe
chkBIOSsupport.exe
cTimerBucketsSieve.exe
DDUsbDiag.exe
devcon.exe
Disk.exe
dowin.exe
eventLog.exe
Exec.exe
Fan.exe
IEEE1394.exe
KeyBoard.exe
Memory.exe
NBPanel.exe
PCIe.exe
PCIe2.exe
Processor.exe
sed.exe
Serial.exe
ServerMgmt.exe
sigcheck64.exe
SMITest.exe
SMViewer.exe
SysMan.exe
SystemConfig.exe
SystemConfig2.exe
TouchPad.exe
TouchScreen.exe
UnloadDDDriver.exe
UpdateVersion.exe
Validate.exe
Video.exe
winGui.exe

c:\tc2\s\ADDF\x64\Release>
```